# C++ - recursion for loop - how to get access to various iterators

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, recursion, iterator

I would like to make recursion in for loop with access to following iterators independently.
I tried to do that, but it looks like nested loop doesn't update its parent iterator. I am not sure what's wrong here:

```
    std::vector<int> it;
    // some code that fill "it" vector

    std::vector<int *> iter;
    for(int i=0; i<it.size(); i++)
    {
        iter.push_back(&it(i));
    }

    int sweek = 0;
    int dup=0;

    // And now call the function which definition is:
    void matrixRecursion()
    {
        int start = sweek;
        int end = matrix[sweek];

        for(it(start); it(start)<end; it(start)++)
        {
            if(sweek < it.size()-1)
            {
                sweek++;
                matrixRecursion();
            }
            else
            {
                for(int t=0; t<it.size(); t++)
                {
                    dup += nIndex[*iter[t]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For example lets say `it.size()` is 3. Then if everything would work as I expect the result should be like that:

```
for(int i=0; i<matrix[0]; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<matrix[1]; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<matrix[2]; k++)
        {
            dup += nIndex[i] + nIndex[j] + nIndex[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides you shadowing the variable `i` in one of the inner loops, you have to remember that `i` is a *local* variable. Not only local inside the function but local inside the *loop*. As soon as the outer loop ends, the pointers to `i` that you have stored in the vector will be invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here, but my guess is that `std::vector<int> iter;` might be better.

Comment: *Furthermore*, the pointers you push in one call will all be pointing to *one single* variable. All the pointers from one call will be all the same. All in all, ***why*** are you pushing pointers? Why not push the *value* of `i`?

Comment: I push `i` because later when `i` iterate to next value, the value in my vector will not be updated. That's how I see that